# How do I log the entire trace back of a Ruby exception using the default Rails logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I am working on rails project and I am trying to get exceptions to be logged to the rails log files.  I know I can call `logger.error $!` to get the first line of the exception logged to the file.  But, I want to get the entire trace stack logged as well.  How do I log the entire trace back of an exception using the default rails logger?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
logger.error $!.backtrace
```

Also, don't forget you can

```
rescue ErrorType => error_name
```

to give your error a variable name other than the default `$!`.

Comment: Am I missing something? logger.error only takes a single argument, so that code does not work...

Comment: This one doesn't work, use `logger.error e.message + "\n  " + e.backtrace.join("\n  ")` instead.

Comment: I could swear the multiple parameters worked 4 years ago, but maybe it didn't. I've updated it to just log the backtrace, which seems to be the most relevant aspect of the question; I trust the reader can figure out multiple logger calls are possible, ditto for string concatenation (or more Ruby-y, interpolation).

Comment: don't do join('\n') single quotes :p

Answer (score 18):

The way rails does it is

```
137             logger.fatal(
138               "\n\n#{exception.class} (#{exception.message}):\n    " +
139               clean_backtrace(exception).join("\n    ") +
140               "\n\n"
141             )

248       def clean_backtrace(exception)
249         if backtrace = exception.backtrace
250           if defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
251             backtrace.map { |line| line.sub RAILS_ROOT, '' }
252           else
253             backtrace
254           end
255         end
256       end
```

Answer (score 11):

In later versions of Rails, simply uncomment the following line in RAIL_ROOT/config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb (or add this file itself if it's not there):

```
# Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
```

This way you get the full backtrace written to the log on an exception. This works for me in v2.3.4.

Comment: It's part of the documentation for Rails 3.2.3. See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html

Answer (score 6):

`logger.error caller.join("\n")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

In Rails, `ActionController::Rescue` deals with it. In my application controller actions, i'm using method `log_error` from this module to pretty-format backtrace in logs:

```
def foo_action
  # break something in here
rescue
  log_error($!)
  # call firemen
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

http://gist.github.com/127708

Here's the ri documentation for Exception#backtrace:

http://gist.github.com/127710

Note that you could also use Kernel#caller, which gives you the full trace (minus the curent frame) as well.

http://gist.github.com/127709

Also - Note that if you are trying to catch *all* exceptions, you should rescue from Exception, not RuntimeError.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ruby's default variables, like this:

```
logger.error "Your error message. Exception message:#{$!} Stacktrace:#{$@}"
```