# How to log stack traces in node.js

Tags: node.js, logging, stack-trace

Looking for a node.js package that handles stack tracing similar to how this is done in RoR:

[Rails: Logging the entire stack trace of an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484337/rails-logging-the-entire-stack-trace-of-an-exception)

Comment: What "stack trace package" in Rails are you talking about?

Comment: I updated the question to add a link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a stack trace in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can get this text off of the `.stack` property from any Error. For instance:

```
try {
    throw new Error();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

or just `new` up an error for the purposes of getting the stack trace

```
console.log(new Error().stack)
```

Comment: It would need to be `(new Error()).stack`. `new Error().stack` would get `Error().stack` and then try to construct something out of it

Comment: no, that's not true in js the ``new`` operator always takes precedence.

Comment: You should actually use `console.error` instead of `console.log`. They may appear to do the same thing, but actually using the former outputs to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: Especially useful in `electron` applications where `console.trace()` doesn't always work.

Answer (score 9):

there's a function for that: `console.trace()`

In case you don't want to log to console you can get the stack trace string value using `new Error().stack`

Comment: I had no idea that method existed..I'll give this a try!

Comment: Ya, but what if you need to like.. iono.. pass it around, or do something with it? The console functions are called "helper" functions for a reason - they're just so you can be really lazy in specific cases ; )

Comment: that sounds like a big "what if" based on original question, but let me update for that.

Comment: Not a big whatif at all.  I report my error messages to a centralized logging store.  Thank you much for the update!

Answer (score 9):

If you use [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston), you can add this:

```js
winston = require('winston');

logger = expandErrors(new winston.Logger());

logger.info(new Error("my error"));

// Extend a winston by making it expand errors when passed in as the 
// second argument (the first argument is the log level).
function expandErrors(logger) {
  var oldLogFunc = logger.log;
  logger.log = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    if (args.length >= 2 && args[1] instanceof Error) {
      args[1] = args[1].stack;
    }
    return oldLogFunc.apply(this, args);
  };
  return logger;
}
```

and then you get winston loggers with stack traces.  Also is in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/johndgiese/59bd96360ce411042294).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [callsite](https://github.com/visionmedia/callsite), this grabs the stack object so you can use it any way you like (and as an object, rather than a string). Its pretty awesome, and nice and simple. Check out [this](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi) for more info on playing with the stack

There are a few excellent loggers out there for Node.js already, but I built a logger that outputs a colorized, simple output and brief stack trace. It doesn't override console.log, which I find to be handy. If you're interested, you can find it [here, node-logger](https://www.npmjs.org/package/arsenic-logger).

Comment: The implementation of callsite is consistent with the suggestion from @Benja.